# How to link a iOS4-only static library without breaking my app on iOS3.x

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone app that I still support on iOS3.1. I'm trying to add a new feature that requires a third-party static library with a requirement of iOS4. When I link my app to the static library it works fine on iOS4 but fails to start on iOS3.1 because of missing symbols (NSCache) from the static library.

Is there any way to conditionally link the static library so that it loads under iOS4 but not under iOS3?

Comment: And you have no access to the original source for this static library?

Comment: I'm not sure this will cut it in this case, but have you tried weak-linking the offending state library? (marking it optional under "link binary with libraries" in the target's build phases.)

Comment: I don't have access to the source of the library. I tried weak-linking it and it didn't help. I ended up contacting the developer of the library and he had to rebuild the library weak-linking any iOS4 frameworks and setting deployment target of the library to iOS3.1.

Comment: Is it crucial to support iOS 3.x? perhaps it would be wise to just say your users need iOS 4, which is over a year old already, and no devices sold today are unable to run iOS 4.0.

Comment: It's not a new app and I still get quite a few complaints if something stops working on iOS3.x. I think after iOS5 is released I will eventually stop supporting iOS3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is.

First you will have to conditionally load the library. for that, on other link flags, you will create specific libraries load for each architecture/OS version. You can do that on linking menu on build settings from target.

Make sure to have weak linking on the libs, and not to use -load_all flag for the 3.x ios versions.

Comment: How do I "create specific libraries load for each architecture/OS version"? I see that I can set different linker flags depending on the current scheme (Debug, Release or AppStore), but no on the iOS version.

Comment: Yes... if you click on the + button of each scheme to add a new one, you can specify the architecture (armV6 pr V7) and IOS Version.